# Common traits of functions which are non-trivial to integrate?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

My question is very simple: do there exist certain qualities of functions such that functions which possess these qualities are guaranteed not to have anti-derivatives which are expressable in terms of elementary functions? There are, of course, families of functions which cannot be integrated (e.g. $e^{x^n}, |n|>1$) but these are not what I am asking about. I am asking about whether it is possibly to tell that certain functions aren't integrable simply by 'looking at them'? References on this subject, as well as any and all insights are welcome.

Comment: you probably mean $n>1$. And you're not asking about non integrability, but about impossibility to express the integral with usual functions. Maybe you can modify the title ?

Comment: Can do =). Thanks for the feedback

Comment: It can be very subtle. For example the function $$f(x)=\frac x {\sqrt{x^4+10x^2-96x-71}}$$ does have an elementary antiderivative, but if you change $71$ to $72$, it doesn't. Read more on the [Wikipedia page on the Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).